# How to check input text into web form? java script

Tags: javascript

how to check input text before POST operation? it must be numbers only

```
<form method="post" action="credit.php">
Сумма кредита: <input type="text" name="sum"> <br />
первый взнос: <input type="text" name="pv"> <br />
Срок: <input type="text" name="srok"> <br />
Процентная ставка: <input type="text" name="percent"> <br />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you using a library such as JQuery? Jquery has plugins like Jquery.Validate

Comment: Do you use jQuery or other JavaScript framework? Also, suggestion: use labels to wrap text related to each input, and maybe div to wrap label and input, instead of breaks.

Answer (score 4):

Use some kind of javascript..

```
<form method="post" action="credit.php" onsubmit="validateForm()">
<input type="text" name="pv" id="pv"> <br />
....
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
  var result =  /^\d+$/.test(document.getElementById('pv').value);
  return result

}
</script>
```

If your onsubmit returns false, the form won't go. If it returns true, the form will submit.

Comment: how to alert, when user's input is not a number?

Comment: and at input may be decimal (fraction). how to be with this?

Comment: How to alert?    alert("Please enter a number"); return false;

Comment: Make a regular expression to check what you want. A regular expression for decimal is ^\d*.?\d*$